# 3 unknown equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a three-unknown equation. I have to get three lines there.

Let a = a three digit number, e.g 246, 371 //just for further thinking
Let x = a's ones place
Let y = a's tenths place
Let z = a's hundreds place

I've got these two lines already, just cannot get the third.

### x + y + z = 11

### 3x = y

**Here i have to put this into maths**: If we flip the number like: 246 -> 642 or 371 -> 173 the new number is bigger than the old number by 297.

**EDIT** Added more information (because I messed something up there):
All the three digits of the number added must equal 11;
The ones place is 3 times bigger than the tens place;
Flipped number is 297 greater than the original number;

Can you help me figure this out?
Would really appreciate you help!!

**EDIT2**:The final equation system:
$$x+y+z=11$$
$$100x+10y+z−(100z+10y+x)=99(x−z)=297⟹x−z=3$$
$$x=3y$$
Thanks to Math Lover!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the number is $100z+10y+x$ and the flipped number is $100x+10y+z$. Consequently,
$$100x+10y+z - (100z+10y+x) = 99(x-z)=297 \implies x-z = 3.$$

Comment: I think you've reversed the roles of $x$ and $z$. In the OP, $z$ is the hundreds digit of the original number.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Thanks. Corrected!

Comment: I've missed a mistake I made in the second statement there.

Comment: It should be that the ones place is 3 times bigger than the tenths place. So is it 3x = y?

Comment: Because right now I get the answers (x,y,z)= (14/5;42/5;-1/5). This cannot translate to a 3 digit number :/

Comment: @Kerdo `It should be that the ones place is 3 times bigger than the tenths place. So is it 3x=y?` No, in that case, $x = 3y$.

Comment: @MathLover Huge thanks to you! Got it all figured out now! :)